# How to trigger an event of TreeView control after a certain time?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, events, event-handling

I am using a treeview control in my project. I need to trigger an event in treeview only after a certain time, because when the user tries to select a certain item randomly, it triggers an event for every items passed while selecting till he confirms the item. How to do that?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timer and enable it on TreeView event and disable within Tick event when completed.

Comment: Disable *and* enable in the event handler.  To ensure the timer gets restarted.